# To reach k set consensus (k=2)

Tags: distributed-systems

If I can use FIFO queue and read/write registers, can I reach wait free 2 set consensus if I have 3 processes? I thought is I can, but I saw a conclusion from text book says "we cannot achieve 2 set consensus on 3 processes in shared memory system", so I'm confused now.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from Chapter 16 of [the book:
Distributed Computing: Fundamentals, Simulations, and Advanced Topics (2004)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=983102):

> (Page 345) We now show that there is no algorithm for solving $k$-set consensus in the presence of $f \ge k$ failures.

and

> (Page 351) **Theorem 16.7** There is no wait-free algorithm for solving $2$-set consensus problem in an asynchronous shared memory system with three processors.

The proof is quite complicated. See also [the paper: The Asynchronous Computability Theorem for $t$-Resilient Tasks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2ec4/f903fb9cc1c12baa05bfb4a0e686fed9321c.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. A FIFO queue has consensus number 2, thus you can implement 2-processors consensus using FIFO queues and registers. So, let processor 1 just decide its own input, and let processors 2 and 3 use 2-processors consensus to agree on one of their inputs and decide it. At most 2 values will be decided, thus solving 2-set-consensus among 3 processors.

Note that it is impossible to implement set-consensus using only shared memory (i.e. read-write registers). In distributed computing, a shared-memory system usually means a system in which only read-write registers are present, hence your textbook quote.